# Angular 2: How to modify json feed before giving it to template

Tags: json, angular

From json I get this:

```
{
    "name": "Leonardo",
    "weapon": "sword"
},
{
    "name": "Donatello",
    "weapon": "stick"
},
{
    "name": "Michelangelo",
    "weapon": "nunchucks"
},
{
    "name": "Raphael",
    "weapon": "sai"
}
```

But for template I want to insert one extra field dynamically:

```
{
    "name": "Leonardo",
    "weapon": "sword"
    "is_leader": "true"
},
{
    "name": "Donatello",
    "weapon": "stick"
    "is_leader": "false"
},
{
    "name": "Michelangelo",
    "weapon": "nunchucks"
    "is_leader": "false"
},
{
    "name": "Raphael",
    "weapon": "sai"
    "is_leader": "false"
}
```

But I can't even get component to return the observable (says it's undefined, but renders ok in template). So far I have this in my component.

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getTestData().subscribe(res => this.allData = res);
}
```

Comment: is this open json objects or array of json objects, if its an array then simply loop through it and add your property whats the challenge here ?

Comment: show the `getTestData` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the data from `.map()`

Here is the logic how you can achieve that will current given code :

```
.subscribe(res => {
    this.allData = res.map(e => {
        e['is_leader'] = true; // as per your rule;
        return e;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With `HttpClient` which came with Angular 4.3+, you could use interceptors (`HttpIntercept`) to intercept, filter and/or modify you incoming JSON feed. A bit of googling shows how to setup interceptors and use them like [here](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/) for example.